# resize / from /home

Tags: linux, lvm

I would like to add the 150G from `/home` to `/`

Do I need to do it with live DC?

it will delete my data?

[image]

Comment: What filesystem are `/` and `/home` (e.g., ext4, xfs, btrfs, zfs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `/home` is only 150G in size, moving 150G from `/home` to `/` means **completely destroying** the `/home` LV.

The procedure would be:

1.) Backup everything in `/home` that you don't wish to lose.

2.) If possible, login on the console as root so `/home` won't be in use, and unmount `/home`.

If that's not possible, you'll need to comment out the line for the `/home` filesystem in `/etc/fstab` and reboot, so the system will come up without mounting `/home`. In this situation, you should be still able to login with SSH or in text mode, but GUI logins as regular users won't be possible as there will be no writeable home directories for regular users. A GUI login needs to write a few small files to the user's home directory.

3.) Once `/home` is unmounted, run the following commands. (Note: **this is the destructive step**: after these commands, the only way to get the contents of your old `/home` back is from backups you made in step #1.)

```
lvremove /dev/centos/home
lvextend -L +150G -r /dev/centos/root
```

If your Linux distribution is not new enough to support the `-r` option for `lvextend`, you can omit that option and then use a filesystem-specific command to extend the root filesystem. For `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4` filesystem types, the command would be `resize2fs /dev/centos/root`. For a XFS filesystem, the command would be `xfs_growfs /`.

CentOS 7 and above use the XFS filesystem type by default; older CentOS releases are likely to use `ext4`.

4.) Finally, restore/recreate the users' home directories under `/home` (it will now be a regular empty directory that was previously used as a mount point).